# How to filter private user to user interactions?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm creating a private user to user chat system, for now I'm displaying all of the objects through the views in the profile of the user like this `user = userComment.objects.all()`.

The problem with that is that everyone can read everyone's chat messages and I would like to filter it so only the recipient and the sender can read the messages they send to each other.

If if filter it like so : `userComment.objects.filter(sender=request.user)` then only sended message will be shown.

If I filter it like that : `userComment.objects.filter(recipient=request.user)` then only received message will be shown.

I would like to filter it so **only** the recipient and the sender can read their chat.

Why do I want to filter it into one variable ? So it can look like this : [image]

And **not** like this :

[image]

**models.py**

```
class userChat(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="receiver")
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sent_at)
```

template/**file.html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.client == request.user %}
            <li style="text-align:left; background:yellow;">
                <p>from {{ user.client }} to <strong>{{ user.worker }} </strong> | {{ user.sent_at }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.comment }}</p>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li style="text-align:right; background:#eaeaea;">
                <p>from {{ user.client }} to <strong>{{ user.worker }}</strong> | {{ user.sent_at }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.comment }}</p>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Update : Following Daniel Roseman's example I've tried this :

```
filter(Q(recipient=request.user) | Q(sender=request.user)).order_by('sent_at')
```

The problem is that another user can still see the chat messages between the recipient and the sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Q` to do an OR query.

```
from django.db.models import Q
UserComment.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))
```

Comment: There is a problem with that, I want the the the objects to be ordered by datetime (sent_at), the example you sent me order it as the second image example I've added, should I use an order_by, but then how ?

Comment: Just add it to the end as normal.

Comment: check the update, the problem is that another user can still see the chat messages between the recipient and the sender.

Comment: /comment/<sender username>

Comment: Then surely you just need to check in that view whether username is the current user.

Comment: Well, here is some news, I know that the user that have nothing to do with the chat can't see the messages, but the new issue is that if the "recipient" or the "sender" goes to the user that has nothing to do with them, then they'll see the messages there too.

Comment: You are missing permission restriction on the view.